# SQL Server Datetime manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have the following query below that computes a certain amount based on the Date Differences.  However, I could not execute the query because of the error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Query:

```
declare @var1 datetime
declare @var2 datetime          

set @var1 = '2015-07-14 13:31:43.797'
set @var2 = '2015-07-14 13:31:43.797'

select 
    'Reefer' = 
    case
        when DATEDIFF (hh,@var1,@var2) <= 6 and DATEDIFF (hh, @var1, @var2) > 0
          then 429.000
          else
            case 
                when (DATEDIFF (hh,@var1,@var2) % 6) > 0
                    then 429.00 * ((DATEDIFF (hh,@var1,@var2) / 6)+ 1) 
                else 'wut'
            end
    end 
from 
    container con
inner join 
    containerdetail cod on con.containernumber = cod.containernumber
left join 
    dea on dea.containernumber = con.containernumber
where 
    con.billofladingnumber = 'IMPJCP07140003'
```

Comment: at what line is this error occurring?

Comment: to be exact, the error message is : "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: I would assume the problem is 'wut'

Comment: Be careful with datediff and hours, it might not be obvious, but the difference between 11:59 and 12:00 is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use multi types in `CASE` branches:

Edit `else 'wut'` to `else 0`

Comment: well, that was embarrassing.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Proper reason is *The data types of input_expression and each when_expression must be the same or must be an implicit conversion*

Answer (score 1):

You have problem because you have different datatypes on `THEN` and `ELSE` parts, It should be the same. You can fix It by converting `THEN` part of `INT` datatype to `NVARCHAR()` in following:

```
case 
  when (DATEDIFF (hh,@var1,@var2) % 6) > 0
        then CAST(429.00 * ((DATEDIFF (hh,@var1,@var2) / 6)+ 1) AS VARCHAR(20))
    else 'wut'
end
```

Also this part `then 429.000` should be converted to `NVARCHAR()`:

`THEN CAST(429.000 AS NVARCHAR(20))`